# UNIX | Use awk to pull out specific values from a log file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I am trying to extract specific values from a logfile like below :

```
Table "xxx"."xxxx":

  3785568 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Bind array size not used in direct path.
Column array  rows :    5000
Stream buffer bytes:  256000
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:       3785568
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader main thread:      878
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader load thread:      796

Run began on Fri Sep 01 04:00:26 2017
Run ended on Fri Sep 01 04:04:45 2017

Elapsed time was:     00:04:19.24
CPU time was:         00:00:08.56
```

---

What i would like to retrieve are :

```
3785568 as number_rows
Sep 01 04:00:26 2017 as start_time
Sep 01 04:04:45 2017 as end_time
```

How is this possible this extraction with awk?

Any help would be really much appreciated :)

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for your given file this works:

```
awk '/Rows/{ if (++n==1){ print $1 } }/began/ || /ended/{ print $5,$6,$7,$8 }' log.file
```

output:

```
3785568
Sep 01 04:00:26 2017
Sep 01 04:04:45 2017
```

Comment: `BEGIN{ OFS = " " }` is doing nothing useful, just setting OFS to the default value it already has.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was in a hurry in getting to lunch there :)

Comment: @JFS31, another hot question please! If I want to add to this awk you provided one more argument extractrion, the table name **without quotes** how could this be achieved?????

Comment: This should do: awk '/^Table/{ gsub(/"||:/,"",$2); print $2 }/Rows/{ if (++n==1){ print $1 } }/began/ || /ended/{ print $5,$6,$7,$8 }' it gives you the table name without quotes and the : at the end. And next time it would be nice if you would ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @JFS31 Thanks, but this awk does not do the desired output.For more details, I logged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073193/awk-spool-specific-values-to-csv-file-load-to-oracle-without-quotesawkunix?noredirect=1#comment79107226_46073193

could you please have a look? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/Rows successfully loaded/{
        print $1 " as number_rows"
        next
    }
    /Run began on/{ 
        sub(/Run began on /,""); 
        print $0 " as start_time"
        next 
   }
   /Run ended on/{
        sub(/Run ended on /,"");    
        print $0 " as end_time"
   }' infile
```

***Input***

```
$ cat infile
Table "xxx"."xxxx":

  3785568 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Bind array size not used in direct path.
Column array  rows :    5000
Stream buffer bytes:  256000
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:       3785568
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader main thread:      878
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader load thread:      796

Run began on Fri Sep 01 04:00:26 2017
Run ended on Fri Sep 01 04:04:45 2017

Elapsed time was:     00:04:19.24
CPU time was:         00:00:08.56
```

***Output***

```
$ awk '/Rows successfully loaded/{
      print $1 " as number_rows"
      next
  }
  /Run began on/{ 
      sub(/Run began on /,""); 
      print $0 " as start_time"
      next 
  }
  /Run ended on/{
      sub(/Run ended on /,""); 
      print $0 " as end_time"
  }' infile

3785568 as number_rows
Fri Sep 01 04:00:26 2017 as start_time
Fri Sep 01 04:04:45 2017 as end_time
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose better solution is `grep`

```
ROWS=`grep "Total logical records read" logfile.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` 
START=`grep "Run began on " | cut -d" " -f4-`
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind **Perl** or `grep` with `-P`

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /\d+ (?=Rows successfully)|^Run (began|ended) on Fri \K[^\n\r]+/g' file
```

it outputs:

```
3785568 
Sep 01 04:00:26 2017
Sep 01 04:04:45 2017
```

### or:

```
grep -Po '\d+ (?=Rows successfully)|^Run (began|ended) on Fri \K[^\n\r]+' file
```

Comment: Very good idea, although I dont prefer perl on my prod machine!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]Rows successfully/ { print $1" as number_rows" } /^Run began on .*$/ { print $4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" as start_time" } /^Run ended on .*$/ { print $4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" as end_time"}' filename
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '/Rows success/{ print $1 }/^Run (began|ended)/{ print $5,$6,$7,$8 }' file
```

The output:

```
3785568
Sep 01 04:00:26 2017
Sep 01 04:04:45 2017
```

Comment: Dear Roman, very good one as well, thank you, already answered by JFS31 above!