# awk spool specific values to CSV file (load to oracle) without quotes|awk|unix

Tags: bash, oracle, csv, unix, awk

I am trying to extract specific values from a logfile like below :

```
Table "OWNER123"."MYTABLE":

  3785568 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Bind array size not used in direct path.
Column array  rows :    5000
Stream buffer bytes:  256000
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:       3785568
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader main thread:      878
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader load thread:      796

Run began on Fri Sep 01 04:00:26 2017
Run ended on Fri Sep 01 04:04:45 2017

Elapsed time was:     00:04:19.24
CPU time was:         00:00:08.56
```

What i would like to retrieve is to spool the output to a specific CSV file with below format (no quotes) :

```
MYTABLE,3785568,Sep 01 04:00:26 2017, Sep 01 04:04:45 2017
```

How is this possible this extraction with one single awk command?

Any help would be really much appreciated :)

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If you are specifically looking for a way to parse that logfile using AWK then you might be better posting at https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oneliner**

```
awk -v OFS=, '/^Table/{gsub(/.*\.|[":]/,""); table=$0;next}/Rows successfully loaded/{rows = $1;next}/Run began on/{ sub(/Run began on /,""); start = $0 ;next }/Run ended on/{sub(/Run ended on /,"");print table, rows, start, $0}' logfile
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` at the start of this script to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` ,`/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

***Script***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat parse.awk
/^Table/{
    gsub(/.*\.|[":]/,"");
    table=$0
    next
}
/Rows successfully loaded/{
        rows = $1
        next
}
/Run began on/{ 
        sub(/Run began on /,""); 
        start = $0 
        next 
}
/Run ended on/{
        sub(/Run ended on /,"");    
        print table, rows, start, $0
        exit
}
```

***Execution & Output***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -v OFS=, -f parse.awk logfile 
MYTABLE,3785568,Fri Sep 01 04:00:26 2017,Fri Sep 01 04:04:45 2017
```

***Input***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat logfile 
Table "OWNER123"."MYTABLE":

  3785568 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Bind array size not used in direct path.
Column array  rows :    5000
Stream buffer bytes:  256000
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:       3785568
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader main thread:      878
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader load thread:      796

Run began on Fri Sep 01 04:00:26 2017
Run ended on Fri Sep 01 04:04:45 2017

Elapsed time was:     00:04:19.24
CPU time was:         00:00:08.56
```

Comment: Hello Akshay! Thaks, good one. But could this be implemented in an one-row awk command??

Comment: @tln_jupiter : added oneliner as requested

Comment: #!/bin/bash
last_year=$(date +%Y)
awk -v OFS=, '/^Table/{gsub(/.*\.|[\":]/,""); table=$0;next}/Rows successfully loaded/{rows = $1;next}/Run began on/{ sub(/Run began on /,""); start = $0 ;next }/Run ended on/{sub(/Run ended on /,"");print table, rows, start, $0}' invoice_SDN_$last_year-0.log > extraction_MSISDN.csv
RET_CODE=$?
echo "Transform script has finished with exit code: $RET_CODE"
exit $RET_CODE

I have automated this to a script.

Why it fails with reason "awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1" ??

Comment: @tln_jupiter: which os ?, If you want to try this on a Solaris/SunOS system, change `awk` at the start of this script to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` ,`/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

Comment: @tln_jupiter glad to know :)

Comment: @tln_jupiter use one of the xpg awks, not nawk. nawk is older and further from POSIX compliance than the xpg awks. There's no point even bringing up nawk in the context of awks available on Solaris since you have the xpg ones available and they are better.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for useful information, Personally I don't have much experience on sun/solaris, in past during migration of our servers we used it, I love to work  mostly  on `gawk`

Comment: Definitely you want to get gawk if at all possible, but if you can't then use an xpg awk. Just forget about nawk and treat /bin/awk like it was a rabid werewolf crapping lava....

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
'BEGIN{ ORS = ","}/^Table/{ gsub(/"||:/,"",$2); split($2, a, "."); print a[2] }/Rows/{ if (++n==1){ print $1 } }/began/ || /ended/{ print $5, $6, $7, $8 }' yourfile.txt | sed 's/,$//'
```

Output:

```
MYTABLE,3785568,Sep 01 04:00:26 2017,Sep 01 04:04:45 2017
```

I guess now you got some idea on how to modify these awk commands.

Comment: thank you so much.
Although it does not work as expected.
For example I executed:
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS = ","}/^Table/{ gsub(/"||:/,"",$2); split($2, a, "."); print a[2] }/Rows/{ if (++n==1){ print $1 } }/began/ || /ended/{ print $5, $6, $7, $8 }' myfile.log | sed 's/,$//' > extraction_INVOICE.csv

and the output to the .csv is:

MYTABLE,,MYTABLE:,3785568,Sep 01 05:30:21 2017,Sep 01 05:45:26 2017



Could you please assist?

Comment: Mhh, from your given input it works for me. Weird that it is printing Mytable,,Mytable: Is the unput you used there any different?

Comment: mmm weird. Could you please check below reply and spot differencies? :)

Comment: Working for me with the command from the reply. But I guess you got your answer :)